# RWeka Neural Network Classifier error

Tags: java, r, rweka

I am using RWeka package to carry out a machine learning experiment, the method runs fine for other machine learning algorithms given by RWeka but whenever I run the neural networks I get the below mentioned error:

```
MLP <- make_Weka_classifier('weka/classifiers/functions/Multilayerperceptron')
BoW_MLP_m <- MLP( y~ ., data = train_data_m,control = Weka_control(N=70,L=0.3))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(man, "Ljava/lang/Object;", "objectForName", as_qualified_name(name)) : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I have the `rJava` library imported and called, so I am a bit confused

Comment: It's just a typo. It's `MLP <- make_Weka_classifier('weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron')` (with the capital P for Perceptron).

Comment: Thank you very much, issue resolved but I get this error now GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Error in .jcall(o, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass"): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded